# Printer not working on Xubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, printing

Is it possible to install Samsung Xpress M2026W to work in Xubuntu 18.04? I was unable to find drivers. But I was wondering if it is possible to get it work in a way that as one wants to print, Xubuntu starts VirtualBox with Windows 10, sends the file from Xubuntu to that Virtualbox and prints there. Or is there some easier approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find drivers for the Samsung Xpress M2026W at support.hp.com [Linux drivers](https://support.hp.com/hk-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-m2026-laser-printer-series/16462610/model/16462614)
They seem to be proprietary drivers, but should be useful for setting up the printer. It seems to have up-to-date packages for the major Linux distributions.

However, you seem to be tied to the proprietary drivers. From the hardware data sheet, this printer does not support neither the PCL nor the Postscript standards.

PS. I would not buy it for using it on non-Windows OS systems.